# lubuntu / centos container CrashLoopBackOff error

Tags: linux, containers, kubectl, crashloopbackoff

when ever i run # kubectl run ubuntu --image=ubuntu  or centos
i gt containercrashoff  , when checked in kubectl describe pod below error is observed

Warning  Failed     4s (x3 over 22s)  kubelet            Error: failed to create containerd task: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "ping": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

pl suggest to solve this issue

Comment: Both of those pods start an interactive shell by default (which exists immediately because it's not attached to a tty). That doesn't make sense for what you're doing. Decide what persistent process you're going to run in those containers and add it as parameters to the `kubectl run` command. E.g., `kubectl run ubuntu --image=ubuntu sleep -- sleep inf`

Comment: i am  new to kubernetes and i was practicing  some basic scenerios which were working earlier but now every container is crashing with the same commands, i have tried the command provided by you but its failing again                                                      # kubectl run ubuntu --image=ubuntu sleep -- sleep inf
pod/ubuntu created
# kubectl get pod
NAME     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
ubuntu   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   1          11

Comment: Have you looked at the pod logs or events to see if there are any clues about why it's failing?

Comment: event output Successfully pulled image "ubuntu" in 2.878713602s
Successfully pulled image "ubuntu" in 2.926146159s
Pulling image "ubuntu"
Created container ubuntu2
Started container ubuntu2
Successfully pulled image "ubuntu" in 2.796668146s
Back-off restarting failed container                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                     
  the containter is succesfully created then get terminated